# EditText losing its content on RecyclerView. How to restore its content?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `EditText` in `RecyclerView`. When I edit the content of a `EditText` and scroll up/down, that same content is displayed in another line. 
Also, If I return to the same position, the `EditText` is empty.

Here is the layout for every item of the `RecyclerView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#F3F2F2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_jantri_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/quicksand_bold"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="@color/theme_color"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/ed_jantri_number"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_jantri_edittext"
                android:fontFamily="@font/quicksand_bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textSize="12dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the Adapter class where I am setting text to the box number:

```
public class AdapterJantri extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterJantri.Myholder> {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Myholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        return new Myholder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_jantri_view, viewGroup, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Myholder myholder, int i) {
        myholder.txtJantriNumber.setText(String.valueOf(i + 1));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 99;
    }

    public class Myholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        EditText edJantriNumber;
        TextView txtJantriNumber;

        public Myholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            edJantriNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ed_jantri_number);
            txtJantriNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_jantri_number);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Activity

```
public class JantriActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    SlideToActView slideToActView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_jantri);
        initiliaization();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new AdapterJantri());
    }

    private void initiliaization() {
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_jantri);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 4));
        slideToActView = findViewById(R.id.swipe_save_transaction);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `ViewAdapter` re-uses a `View`. So, when scrolling, instead of creating new views, an Adapter will re-use a view that is no longer visible.
So, that is the main reason you have the `onBindViewHolder`. With that method, Android gives you chance to update the view content before it becomes visible. If you won't update all contents of the (the `TextView` and the `EditText`), you observe issues like that one that you mentioned.

Note this code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Myholder myholder, int i) {
    myholder.txtJantriNumber.setText(String.valueOf(i + 1));
}
```

As you can see, you are only updating the `TextView`. So, that `TextView` (re-used or not) will always display proper text. However, you are not updating the content of the `EditText`. This way, if the View was just created, the `EditText` is empty. If the view is being re-used, you will see the old value (from a different line).

So, in order to keep update the `EditText` properly, you must store all texts in a separated list. For example:

```
public class AdapterJantri extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterJantri.Myholder> {

    private String[] mTextList;

    public AdapterJantri() {
        mTextList = new String[getItemCount()];
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Myholder myholder, int i) {
        myholder.txtJantriNumber.setText(String.valueOf(i + 1));

        // Here, you update the EditText content
        myholder.edJantriNumber.setText(mTextList[i]);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull final Myholder holder) {
        // Here, you save the text before the view gets recycled
        int index = holder.getAdapterPosition();
        if (index >= 0) {
            mTextList[index] = holder.edJantriNumber.getText().toString();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

If you have a `TextWatcher` and you need to disable it temporarily, I suggest to:

**First**

Don't create a `TextWatcher` inside the `bindViewHolder`. You don't need to create a new one everytime. Just add it and remove it. You can use your own `MyHolder` as a `TextWatcher`

```
public class Myholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements TextWatcher {

    EditText edJantriNumber;
    TextView txtJantriNumber;

    public Myholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        edJantriNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ed_jantri_number);
        txtJantriNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_jantri_number);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(final CharSequence s, final int start, final int count, final int after) {
        // Add your code here
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, final int start, final int before,
            final int count) {
        // Add your code here
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {
        // Add your code here
    }

    public void disableTextChangeListner() {
        // This will remove the listener. So, it will stop to listen to new events
        edJantriNumber.removeTextChangedListener(this);
    }

    public void addTextChangeListner() {
        // This will add the listener. So, it will start to listen to new events
        edJantriNumber.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }
}
```

Then, during `bindViewHolder`, disable the listener, set the new text, and add the listener again as foolows:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Myholder myholder, int i) {
    myholder.disableTextChangeListner();
    myholder.txtJantriNumber.setText(String.valueOf(i + 1));
    myholder.edJantriNumber.setText(mTextList[i]);
    myholder.addTextChangeListner();
}
```

Comment: is there any other way i can do it as i have added addOnTextChange lister in bind holder and every time i  it recreate view it settex to edittext which call method addOnTextChange

Comment: Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final Myholder myholder, final int i) {
        myholder.txtJantriNumber.setText(String.valueOf(i + 1));
        myholder.edJantriNumber.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                daT[i] = myholder.edJantriNumber.getText().toString();
                selectSingleItemCallback.selectedItem(daT);
            }
        });
        myholder.edJantriNumber.setText(mTextList[i]);

    }

Comment: I updated the answer.. Note that I also performed a small change on onViewRecycled